# MS Flow, HTTP Webhook with XML payload

Tags: power-automate

I am testing with MS Office Flow and HTTP webhook.
The service that shall call the webhook sends a XML payload

How can I receive the payload as plain string (or parsed XML) in HTTP Webhook trigger?

Example XML payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event>
    <action>deleted</action>
    <type>application</type>
    <object>
        <application>
            <id>1409617991306</id>
            <created_at>2018-10-15T14:00:45+02:00</created_at>
            <updated_at>2018-10-15T14:13:04+02:00</updated_at>
            <state>live</state>
        </application>
    </object>
</event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, clicking "see more" and pick "body"

[image]

Comment: can you help with https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305125/get-value-from-http-response-xml-and-pass-it-as-a-field-in-next-http-request-fie